# Padding or margins is only on left and right side but not on top and bottom

Tags: android, xml, margin, frame, padding

When I am trying to make a border (frame) around my `ImageView` by using padding or margin in `FrameLayout` (in code it has id: `main_frame`), it's only shown on left and right sides but not on top and bottom.

But as I wrote I need it around because it should look like frame.

There is a code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context=".WallActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wall_frame"
        android:layout_width="592dp"
        android:layout_height="315dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/wall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/room"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.621"
            android:layout_margin="40dp">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/frame"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:padding="20dp">


                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/mat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:background="@android:color/white"
                    android:visibility="visible"
                    android:padding="10dp">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/imageholder"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/picture"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                            android:src="@drawable/nature"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>

                </FrameLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="586dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="35.5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hideBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/menubutton"
            android:text="Hide"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clearBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/menubutton"
            android:text="Clear"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lockBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/menubutton"
            android:text="Lock"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exportBTN"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/menubutton"
            android:text="Export"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/wallBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/menubutton"
            android:text="Wall"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pictureBtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:background="@drawable/menubutton"
            android:text="Picture"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorGrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the screenshot.

[image]

Do you have any idea how to solve it? I tried searching but couldn't find anything similar. Or is there a better way to make frames?

Thank you!

//Edited:

I added full xml code, added some padding to FrameLayouts with id: mat, frame. It looks perfect but main_frame is still broken. main_frame should be invisible (with transparent color) so you may think it's not necessarily to solve it, but I find out when I let it be like that it brokes image when I change it. It adds some white borders (only just on left and right side) to the image...

There is another picture to show you that frames look good but as I said main_frame is broken...

[image]

Comment: Please provide the full xml (i.e. text part of your layout).

Answer (score 0):

Add this: `android:padding="2dp"` to the FrameLayout with id `frame`. You can change 2dp to what you like.

Comment: frame and mat works properly. only main_frame is broken... But thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider having a simple layout using one `RelativeLayout` and an `ImageView`. The `RelativeLayout` might have a background whereas the `ImageView` will have some padding along with a background as well. So the layout will be something like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/room">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/nature" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried it, but it looks the same. Using this make on top and on bottom some "frame" but it still has smaller size than on sides. But thank you. I will add full xml, as you write maybe I got something wrong somewhere else...